# How to get data through audio port in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I  want to get data using serial port via audio jack. I don't have any idea about this.
I found the app square they read the data through port.so does any one know how to get data or is there any projects similar like this.

Answer (score 1):

[Romotive](http://romotive.com/developers), a project that helps you make robots out of smartphones uses the audio jack for data transfer, and I think the software is open source.